# jquery Delay dialog loading?

Tags: delayed-job, jquery-dialog

How can i delay Dialog loading for like 2-3 sec

```
 $("#dialog-model").dialog({
    height: 250,
    width: 350,
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function () {
            window.location = "/MyURL";
        },
        "No": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    },
    modal: true
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use setTimeout

```
var seconds=3000;
setTimeout(
function(){
    $("#dialog-model").dialog({
        height: 250,
        width: 350,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                window.location = "/MyURL";
            },
            "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        },
        modal: true
    });
},seconds);
```